# DB2 ERRORCODE=-4229, SQLSTATE=null

Tags: db2

I'm getting this error while executing a batch operation.
`Use getNextException() to retrieve the exceptions for specific batched elements.ERRORCODE=-4229, SQLSTATE=null`

I'm not finding any pointer to proceed with debugging this error.

Appreciating any help!!!

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21623212

Comment: Did you try calling getNextException() to see if it provided any additional details? http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/javaentnut_2/index3.html

Comment: Actually this batch operation is inside a jar file which is being called so unable to call getNextException()

Comment: Have you checked the connexion to DB2 directly from the CLP? db2 connect to xxx, and then do the same operation there. It is weird to not have a sqlstate

Comment: Atlast got the additional error message from db2.
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-530, SQLSTATE=23503
Looks like it is related to PK duplicate records being inserted.

Comment: Did the CLP execution helped to solve or at least understand the problem?

Comment: I dont have direct access to DB2.. but somehow the extra exception came up in the logs in my application..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who are looking for an solution to this error.

For me this was due to

`THE INSERT OR UPDATE VALUE OF FOREIGN KEY constraint-name IS INVALID.
 DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-530, SQLSTATE=23503`

Comment: Actually that is one of the reasons that could trigger this error. Check my answer below

Answer (score 7):

Search for the error on the IBM page:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.java%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fimjcc_rjvjcsqc.htm

> -**4229** Message text: text-from-getMessage Explanation: An error occurred during a batch execution.
>
> User response: Call SQLException.getMessage to retrieve specific
>   information about the problem.

So, it might be related to any underlying error during the execution of your batch insert/update/delete

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this occurred because I had an unique covering index defined on two columns and the combination of these two values was not unique when I was inserting the records.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is still wondering, try entering a unique record and check if the error still persists?
For me it was because of duplicate entry of a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was due to having rows in the database with the same PK IDs that the sequence was generating. The solution can be to fix these "future" row IDs or adapt the sequence to jump those numbers.